# generate dataframe with different values in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe such that each ab values have for each dates. Please help!

```
ab <- c("ab","cd")
dates <- c("Jan 2018","Jan 2019","Mar 2019")
```

Expected_Output:

```
  ab    dates
1 ab Jan 2018
2 ab Jan 2019
3 ab Mar 2019
4 cd Jan 2018
5 cd Jan 2019
6 cd Mar 2019
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tidyr`,  this can be done with `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(ab, dates)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  ab    dates   
#  <chr> <chr>   
#1 ab    Jan 2018
#2 ab    Jan 2019
#3 ab    Mar 2019
#4 cd    Jan 2018
#5 cd    Jan 2019
#6 cd    Mar 2019
```

---

Or using `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(ab, dates)
```

---

Or using `expand.grid` from `base R`

```
expand.grid(ab = ab, dates = dates)
```